# "On Horse Market" vs. "On the Horse Market" as the title for a post

Tags: articles, definite-article

"On Horse Market"

or

"On the Horse Market"

I suspect the latter is correct, but I do not know why?
I did some [research](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/market). I know that *market* is countable.
Is that a rule that I always have to put an article before countable nouns?

Comment: Can you add some more context? Neither "On Horse Market" nor "On the Horse Market" make much sense standing alone.

Comment: Mike Harris: The phrase is to be the title of my facebook post.

Comment: Unless 'Horse Market' is the name of a website I don't think you can't really use the first one.

Comment: You can use whatever you want in a *title*. Titles don't need to be grammatical—and very often aren't. Titles of most things are simply noun phrases.

Comment: This is basically asking for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although horse markets are rare in the modern world, there are other types of market, *e.g.,* the stock market or the bond market. The word "market" takes an article because it is a countable noun.

> I bought this horse at a horse market

The speaker does not think the specific location is relevant.

> I bought this horse at the horse market last year

implies a specific market for horses that is presumably understood by both speaker and audience.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a rule that I always have to put an article before countable nouns

When the noun is not a proper noun, and referring to something that, in that sentence, can be counted, then yes.

If you can answer the question *which X* sensibly, then X is countable.

> On Horse Market

Proper nouns in English are capitalized.  You don't use an article here because of that.

*Horse Market* also happens to be composed of words that also work as non-proper nouns.  When used in a non-name sense, the normal article rules would apply.

> I went to the horse market that's down the street.
>
> I went to Horse Market yesterday.
>
> I talked to that guy yesterday.
>
> I talked to John yesterday.